# NHibernate Query To filter based on column difference

Tags: c#, asp.net, nhibernate

Following is a snapshot of the Appointment Model:

```
public class Appointment
{
    public virtual DateTime? InTime {get; set;}
    public virtual DateTime? OutTime {get; set;}
}
```

I want all appointments whose duration was less than 2 minutes. Something like:

```
var twoMinutes = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 2, 0);
var query =
            Repository.QueryOver<DomainModel.Models.Appointment>()
                .Where(a => a.OutTime.Value - a.InTime.Value < twoMinutes);
return query.List();
```

Exception:

variable 'a' of type 'DomainModel.Models.Appointment' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined

When I try to this using QueryOver() I get an error. How can I do this using ICriteria or any other way in nHibernate?

Comment: There are server (C#) moments of life, and DB ones. The calculation of the difference is something, what should (must) happen on DB. So... Create a projection computing the result on DB... and compare with param passed from server

Comment: So what you are saying is - this has to be done in two queries - one to get the difference between out time and in time and another to pass the difference and compare with two minutes?

Comment: @mridula That doesn't sound correct to me at all. You'd get more help if you answered Liath's question above.

Comment: I have edited the question to add the error I am getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution here, *as I've already mentioned in the comment,* is to move that comparison into DB. And that should be done *(as far as I know)* with Projection:

```
// two minutes
var twoMinutes = 2d;

// the query
var query = Repository.QueryOver<DomainModel.Models.Appointment>();

// the projection using DATEDIFF
var projection = Projections
    .SqlProjection("DATEDIFF(mi, {alias}.InTime ,{alias}.outTime) as difference"
               , new[] {"difference"}
               , new[] {NHibernateUtil.Double});
```

Now we can use it in a query:

```
query.Where(Restrictions.Ge(projection, twoMinutes));
```

Check the

- [SQL Server DATEDIFF() Function](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datediff.asp)

> DATEDIFF(datepart,startdate,enddate)

*It means that to get positive number the first arg must be older ...*

*NOTE: some things are correctly converted by QueryOver engine into appropriate SQL, but this one is not...*